# How to add list of WHERE clauses in Hibernate JPA CriteriaUpdate [bulk update]

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In JPA/Hibernate, how to make use of following mysql update query?

```
UPDATE ProjectStatus
SET deployable = true
WHERE (projectId = 100 AND team = red) or (projectId = 101 AND team = yellow) or ..
AND vertical = 'ITDept'
```

I have List collection of projectId and team attributes which is input to this method.

```
public ProjectIdTeam {
 private Integer ProjectId;
 private String team;
 //setters and getters
}

public void updateProjectList(List<ProjectIdTeam> projectIdTeamList, String vertical) {

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<ProjectStatus> criteriaUpdate = criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(ProjectStatus.class);
Root<ProjectStatus> lRoot = criteriaUpdate.from(ProjectStatus.class);
lRoot.get("projectId");
lRoot.get("team");
lRoot.get("vertical");

???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine multiple calls to `criteriaBuilder.or` and `criteriaBuilder.and`

```
lRoot.where(
   criteriaBuilder.or(
      criteriaBuilder.and(
         criteriaBuilder.equal(lRoot.get("projectId"), 100),
         criteriaBuilder.equal(lRoot.get("team"), "red")
       ),
       //NEXT CONDITION
   )
)
```